# sorting an array and keep the index in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have an array called **A**, it has **2 Rows** and **56 columns** ( as shown in the attached image)

[image: array]

the first row represents the values while the second row represents the index for each value.

I want to sort the first row but keep the index for each value (I tried to use **Sort** function but it doesnt keep the index of each value in the second row).
for example, let's suppose I have this matrix

input
**x=[9 2 4 3 ;3 1 8 2 ]**

i want the output looks like this 
**y=[2 3 4 9; 1 2 8 3 ];**

Comment: you can use `sortrows`:  `y=sortrows(x')'`

Comment: @Adiel sortrows generates wrong result. You can test this `x=[1 1 1 2 2 3;1 2 1 4 7 1]`

Comment: What the problem with the output of your example? In which manner you consider it "wrong"? Doesn't seem that the OP wants to preserve some original order, or he has any preference to order of duplicate values, especially while it can't be defined "wrong", just a specific case dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this:

```
[y1,I] = sort(x(1,:))

y2 = x(2,I)

y = [ y1 ; y2 ]
```

This basically sort the first row of your data, and save the sorting index in `I`, and then use those index to get the 'sorted' second row, and then just join them

or

```
y = sortrows(x')'
```

The `'` operator transposes the matrix, which allows you to use `sortrows` and then use it again to reshape your output matrix.

Comment: huh, never knew about sortrows!  Funny there is no sortcols equivalent...

Comment: What do you mean wrong result? it gives me the expected output

Comment: please test it with `x=[1 1 1 2 2 3;1 2 1 4 7 1]`

Comment: I get `[1 1 1 2 2 3;1 1 2 4 7 1]`, as expected. I don't see the problem

Comment: result of sortrows :`[1,1,1,2,2,3;1,1,2,4,7,1]` and result of sort `[1,1,1,2,2,3;1,2,1,4,7,1]`

Comment: Yes, they are not same. but that doesn't mean one of them is incorrect. Since we are ordering based on the first row, the position of columns 1,2,3 is exchangeable without a problem. As are columns 4 and 5

Comment: please consider the question "I want to sort `the first row` but keep the index for each value". But sortrows applies lexicographic sort.

Comment: dear all thanks for your answer, by the way, sortrows give the right output and all the other solution as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use indices of sorted elements

```
[S,I]=sort(x(1,:));
result = [S;x(2,I)]
```

The first row is sorted and indices of the sorted elements is used to order the second row.

result

```
2   3   4   9
1   2   8   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the indices directly from sorting the first row.  These can be used as an argument in x itself:

```
x=[9 2 4 3 ;3 1 8 2 ];

%get the indices of the first row:
[~,indices] = sort(x(1,:))

%return x in the order "indices" for each row: 
y = [x(1,indices);x(2,indices)]
```

Comment: Your solution is duplicate of mine